# Get Value from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Best way to get the URL from that string?

```
string text = @"<INMobileCRMConfig>
                    <WebserviceURL>
                       https://179.18.0.30:8200/INPhone/INPhoneMessages/
                    </WebserviceURL>
                </INMobileCRMConfig>";
```

I tried following:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(text);
string url = doc.FirstNode.ToString();
```

and

```
string url = doc.Descendants().Elements("WebserviceURL").Value;
```

and some other simililar things.

Comment: What is the problem with the things you tried?

Comment: seems I had a problem with my debugger o.O it showed me always that the "url" is a `undefined identifier`. As of that I thought my code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(text);
var res = doc.Element("WebserviceURL").Value.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are Ok as you are using Naive xmlelement to read the content.

I would like to add one this is that convert the url to URI after you pull it out from xml.
This will make you sure that URL is correct everytime its pulled.